# Should I use C++ Macros to generate overloaded funcions?

Tags: c++, macros, coding-style

Say I create some function in my class:

```
bool isRisingEdge() {
    return current && !last;
}
```

I also want to generate overloaded versions of this function that accompany it. For the sake of example, let's say I need to overload it with just two different types; the same two types each time. Each overload first calls some function (say `process()`) first, then return my original function.

```
bool isRisingEdge(Signal signal) {
    process(signal);
    return isRisingEdge();
}

bool isRisingEdge(Button button) {
    process(button);
    return isRisingEdge();
}
```

I have many such is...() functions that I want to overload in my class. I could define a macro to help me:

```
#define CREATE_OVERLOADED_FUNCTION(func_, type_) \
type_ func_(Signal signal) { \
    process(signal); \
    return func_(); \
} \
type_ func_(Button button) { \
    process(button); \
    return func_(); \
}
```

...and then use this macro rather than typing out the overloads.

```
bool isRisingEdge() {
    return current && !last;
}

CREATE_OVERLOADED_FUNCTION(isRisingEdge, bool)

bool isFallingEdge() {
    return !current && last;
}

CREATE_OVERLOADED_FUNCTION(isRisingEdge, bool)
```

etc

---

My question is this:

*Should* I be using a macro for a simple purpose like this, or is it better to manually type it out?

Is there a better, non-macro solution?

Macros are shunned by the C++ community, but the Don't Repeat Yourself principle is very important too, and I don't know which "wins".

Comment: Isn't that what templates are for?

Comment: I don't think a template is appropriate in this scenario, as I do not want the class to be generic. It is always being used with these two other types.

Comment: Asking a question like this to the C++ community is like throwing chum into a shark pool :)

Comment: @Jetroid You can use `static_assert` or concepts, to apply such restrictions (way better you ever could do with macros, btw.)